# List devices that are in range of Bluetooth device in Swift

Tags: macos, bluetooth, swift, iobluetooth

I have the following code in a Xcode 6 playground:

```
import Cocoa
import IOBluetooth

class BlueDelegate : IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelegate {
    func deviceInquiryComplete(sender: IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry, error: IOReturn, aborted: Bool) {
        aborted
        var devices = sender.foundDevices()
        for device : AnyObject in devices {
            if let thingy = device as? IOBluetoothDevice {
                thingy.getAddress()
            }
        }
    }
}

var inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry(delegate: BlueDelegate())
inquiry.start()
```

I'm just getting started with Bluetooth under OSX, and all I currently would like is a list of devices in range.

It doesn't seem to be calling my delegate method at all.

I'm new to OSX development and Swift, so be gentle. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To tell a Playground that your code does something in the background, you have to `import XCPlayground` and call `XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()`.
This will keep the IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry alive in the Playground and allow it to call the delegate method when finished.

```
import Cocoa
import IOBluetooth
import XCPlayground

class BlueDelegate : IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelegate {
    func deviceInquiryComplete(sender: IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry, error: IOReturn, aborted: Bool) {
        aborted
        println("called")
        var devices = sender.foundDevices()
        for device : AnyObject in devices {
            if let thingy = device as? IOBluetoothDevice {
                thingy.getAddress()
            }
        }
    }
}

var delegate = BlueDelegate()
var inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry(delegate: delegate)
inquiry.start()
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

While the above approach works, I find it easier to create simple, traditional test projects for tasks that need concepts like async-code, delegation, ...

Comment: How exactly would you do this using a "traditional test projects"?

Comment: Just create a new Xcode project (instead of using a Playground). While using XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely works, a compiled executable (with a runloop and the ability to attach a debugger) is easier to handle when the test project evolves.

Comment: You can find an updated Swift 4.0 answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636726/nearby-bluetooth-devices-using-swift-3-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)